# How to add plugin like filemanager for tinymce in nodejs express?

Tags: node.js, express, ckeditor, tinymce

I am building a simple blog with nodejs express to practice. I want to have an edit (tinymce or ckeditor) that can upload media files from local and manage them for later use. I have found the [filemanager plugin](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) but it is only for php. How can I have such a nodejs on?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem using an external plugin with tinymce. Check this:

Client:

```
 tinymce.init({

       selector: '.editor',
       inline:  false,
       toolbar: 'bold,italic,underline,|,cut,copy,paste,|,undo,redo,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright|,tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor,tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry,|,image,table,charmap,|,fullscreen, code,|,alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
       a_plugin_option: false,
       menubar: false,
       height: 216,
       branding: false,
       plugins: "table link image code fullscreen charmap",
       a_configuration_option: 400,
       autosave_interval: "20s",
       external_plugins: {

         'tiny_mce_wiris': 'https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/tiny_mce/plugin.js'

       },

       images_upload_url: '/upload'
     });
```

And you have to install the following package: [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: function(req, file, cb, res) {

    cb(null, 'public/static/dist/uploads');

  },

  filename: function(req, file, cb, res) {

    var name = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, name);

    return name;
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    "location": 'public/static/dist/uploads/' + req.file.filename
  });
});
```